# Why do I show up as user3417440 instead of my username?

Tags: discussion

Poor me.

Is it because I haven't reached some threshold of score/account age, did I make some kind of mistake or does it just show up like that to me?

I have a name damn it!

Alex

Comment: Did you propogate the name to all profiles and/or wait several hours?

Comment: I don't understand the question, but I thought I set my username when I created my account back in February. It's been a while since then. How do I propagate a name?

Comment: Your username should have showed up immediately after you set it. You may not have saved it (possible due to an error). The only other possibilities I can think of are (1) that you pressed "save and copy to all profiles" on a different Stack Exchange site where you had not set your name, and it overwrote the name you had set, or (2) that your username was obscene and reset by a moderator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your username displays as `user3417440` on the only two sites you're associated with (Stack Overflow and Anime & Manga). If you changed it previously, I'm not sure what might've happened to it.

To change your display name:

1. Click on your stats at the top of any page.
2. Click the "edit" link.
3. Change your display name where indicated. ;)
4. Save it across the entire SE network by clicking "Save ... To All Stack Exchange Accounts"

[image]

[image]

Afterwards, wait awhile to allow the other sites some time to update. There's some amount of cache updating that goes on - I'm not sure whether it applies to profile information.

If you still don't see your username updated after an hour or so, update your question to include what you've tried, and tag it as a `bug` so it gets the attention of the SE team.

Comment: +1 for [freehand circles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/153542).

Comment: -1, that's not a circle, just an arc.

Comment: @OneKitten It's nice to be funny sometimes, but shouldn't downvote useful answers for foolish reasons

Comment: @MrAlien don't worry, I don't actually downvote for those reasons ;)

Comment: You might find that on Meta people can be sarcastic at times.

Comment: @OneKitten yap.. ;)

Comment: Thanks, they call me Qiri now.